# Что не так с SourceTree (вечная ошибка авторизации)?

Tags: bitbucket, source-tree

Всегда в клиенте SourceTree была подключена одна учетная запись Bitbucket, но с недавнего времени их у меня там стало две.

Сначала все было нормально, но теперь со старой (самой первой учетной записью) стала происходить непонятка с авторизацией.

Когда я делаю коммит, то вылезает сообщение об ошибке:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags origin refs/heads/dev:refs/heads/dev 
Pushing to https://colibri@bitbucket.org/colibri/project-ror.git
remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://colibri@bitbucket.org/colibri/project-ror.git/'
Pushing to https://colibri@bitbucket.org/colibri/project-ror.git
remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://colibri@bitbucket.org/colibri/project-ror.git/'
Pushing to https://colibri@bitbucket.org/colibri/project-ror.git
remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://colibri@bitbucket.org/colibri/project-ror.git/'
Pushing to https://colibri@bitbucket.org/colibri/project-ror.git
remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://colibri@bitbucket.org/colibri/project-ror.git/'
Completed with errors, see above
```

Лечится это так:

1. Захожу в настройках в список аккаунтов. Выбираю аккаунт "Colibri" и нажимаю на кнопку "Connect Account". Далее в появившемся окне (где сайт и форма авторизации Bitbucket) я ввожу E-mail и пароль. Все успешно, закрываю окно настроек.
2. Снова делаю коммит. Клиент зачем-то снова просит пароль от "Colibri" - окей, ввожу. И все успешно.

Но лечится таким способом на один раз. То есть следующий коммит придется "обслуживать" точно так же.

В чем дело и как это вылечить навсегда?

Comment: очередная бага в этой софтине. И это ещё безобидная. А есть и деструктивные.  
Пользуйтесь консолькой и забудьте о подобных багах.

Comment: @KoVadim походу придется перевоспитывать себя на консоль.